# How to upgrade MS VS2013 project to MS VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, upgrade, linker-errors

I am trying to build/compile my MS VS2013 c++ project with MS VS2015 under Windows 10.

By linking I got a message:

> Error LNK1171 unable to load mspdb120.dll (error code: 126)

See also screen with settings.
[image: Project settings]
[image: Director]

What is wrong, what should I change?
For what is mspdb120.dll responsible?

Comment: If you are targeting Windows 10 you should probably not select the Platform Toolset for Windows XP.

Comment: I selected platform XP-VS2015 (v140_xp).  Anyhow, now I selected only VS2015 platform and got the same error message.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to change the platform toolset for all build configurations (Debug/Release x86/x64)?

Comment: I checked release/debug, win32/x64. mspdb120.dll - 120 looks like v120 platform. Under VS2015 probably I need v140. But... what have I to change???  In VC++ the evaluated directories are: * Visual studio 14.0 *

Comment: We have tried on PC with VS2015 and VS2013.
So, we selected under VS2015 and WIN 10 the vs120 (MS VS 2013) plarform and also got the same error massage…

Comment: Here is the build log: